# XamlWriter skip template property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to tell the XamlWriter to skip the template property when writing out to a string? I'm trying to mimic a class visually but save off another in the output. I will change the class name by parsing the string, but I'd like to skip the style that mimics the look.

Answer (score 1):

`ShouldSerialize[PropertyName]` is the correct way of customizing whether properties are serialized. Useful for skipping collections if they are empty.

Unfortunately, the Xml writing classes only look inside the owner of a property for the appropriate `Should Serialize` method.

However, If you are trying to skip a property that doesn't belong to you, and it is a DependencyProperty, you're in luck.

You can implement `bool ShouldSerializeProperty(DependencyProperty)` and have control over any DependencyProperty, whether it belongs to your class or not.

In order to skip the Template property, you inherit it as a static member, so the code looks like this:

```
protected override bool ShouldSerializeProperty(DependencyProperty dp)
{
    if (dp == ContentControl.TemplateProperty) return false;
    return base.ShouldSerializeProperty(dp);
}
```